# Regex pattern for script tag pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

```
<script>
my name is john
</script>
```

I want the regular expression for this pattern. I have made regular expression

```
<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>
```

It is detecting the patterns like:

```
<script>my name is john</script>
```

but not detecting the first one , for which I am asking. Maybe because of 'newline'.

Answer (score 4):

In regex `Pattern` pass `DOTALL` flag
`Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>",   Pattern.DOTALL);`

Or you can use embedded flag expression in your regex to add `DOTALL`
`(?s)<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>`

Comment: thank you so much... its working.... now i am feeling stupid that such a small thing did not click in my mind.